# How to turn off anti aliasing on a sprite kit node's texture

Tags: ios, swift, macos, cocoa-touch, sprite-kit

I'm currently trying to put a test game together in Sprite Kit. I have some code that creates a patch of ground using a pair of PNG images with dimensions 200 * 572.

```
let textures = [SKTexture(imageNamed: "GrassAni1"), SKTexture(imageNamed: "GrassAni2")]

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i += 1) {
    let chunk = SKSpriteNode(texture: textures[0])
    chunk.position = CGPointMake(CGFloat(200 * i), 0)
    let animate = SKAction.animateWithTextures(textures, timePerFrame: 1)
    chunk.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(animate))
    //boilerplate physics body code…
    self.addChild(hero)
}
```

Enter my problem. Here is an up-close of my sprite in the Xcode file viewer: [image]

And here's what it looks like when the game is running:[image]
The in-game sprite appears to be anti-aliased and as a result looks fuzzy. How do I prevent this and make the game look as sharp as the original images?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will need to change the `filteringMode` on your `SKTexture` objects to `SKTextureFilteringMode.Nearest`.

Then as long as your node is positioned on pixel boundaries, it should be drawn as expected.

Comment: Works great.  The mode should actually be SKTextureFilteringNearest though.

Comment: @mobopro It's `SKTextureFilteringNearest` if your using ObjC. Swift is `SKTextureFilteringMode.nearest`.